# react wait for another component to finish rendering

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following situtation:
2 components A and B.
A is above B in the page layout.
I wish to calculate B `height` css rule dynamically using it's `top`.
B's `top` is affected by A because A is rendered above it. I attached a reference to B and then apply it style by calculating the bounding rect of the ref and calculating the desired `height` from the `top`.
A problem occurs when component A is taking more time to fully render than component B because A loads images that takes a bit more time to load making B's top to shift a after it was already rendered so the calculating of the `height` in the function needs to be called again somehow after A was fully rendered but I don't wanna make B coupled to A just because it renders before it, what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Simply pass A's height/top down to B as a prop. Also, refs are antipattern.

Comment: They are far from a relationship in the component hierarchy and I don't feel like storing this value in redux seems abusive. And since when refs are antipattern? as far as I know they're perfect for this kind of situation

Comment: Well, reactjs is a top down communication.. refs are implemented but it's not recommended because it defeats reacts original purpose. There is an alternative when two components are far apart; https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html . I personally use it and it's great.

Comment: Yea but I don't think that makes them antipattern for the "right situation" since they're obviously widely used. For the topic, context seems like still an overkill like a store, even so I would have to propagate up the height of A to the shortest common ancestor which seems very wrong in my eyes just for this purpose. Or even if I would just propagate a set function and it's value still seems overkill to me and not right

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using Css flexbox, check code snippet bellow.

```js
(function () {

    var loadImgBtn = document.getElementById('load-image-btn');
    var loadedImg = document.getElementById('loaded-image');
    loadImgBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        loadedImg.style.display = 'block';
    });


})();
```

```css
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    min-height: 350px;
}
#loaded-image {
    display: none;
}

#first-block {
    background: green;
}

#second-block {
    background: red;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
        <div id="first-block"> Component A
            <img id="loaded-image"
                src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
        </div>
        <div id="second-block">Component B</div>
</div>
<button id="load-image-btn">Load Image</button>
```

If you want to calculate it programmatically you can use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) or [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) if you need to pass ref further down something like this

```
const ComponentA = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} className="componentA">
    {props.children}
  </div>
));

const ComponentB = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} className="componentB">
    {props.children}
  </div>
));

class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.refA = React.createRef();
    this.refB = React.createRef();

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.refA.current.clientHeight,this.refB.current.clientHeight);
  }
  render(){

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ComponentA calculatedHeight={componentAHeight} ref={this.refA} >Component A</ComponentA>
        <ComponentB calculatedHeight={componentBHeight} ref={this.refB} >Component B</ComponentB>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

You can do it using [findDOMNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) too (it is depricated in strict mode).  [react-sizeme](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme) might be helpfull as well.